# window.opener.parent doesn't work on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I open a window using

> `window.open();`

After processing on that window I want to write the data in Parent Window element using :

```
var html_high = '<img width="600" src="assets/images/abc.jpg" alt="Image">';
var high = window.opener.parent;
$('#image_area',high.document).html(html_high);
```

`$('#image_area',high.document).html(html_high);` This doesn't work and gives an error in console only in Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0 :

> "SCRIPT65535: Invalid argument"

The above code works on all browser including IE 11,10,9, chrome, mozilla and safari.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with MS Edge. 
You could try storing a reference to the newly opened window and try logging it out to see if there are other properties that have what you are looking for.
No real workarounds that I have seen.
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/828050/ie-11-when-opening-a-new-window-from-another-window-opener-is-undefined

MDN's explanation:

When a window is opened from another window (using Window.open or a link with its target attribute set), it maintains a reference to that first window as window.opener. If the current window has no opener, this method returns NULL.

Windows Phone browser does not support window.opener (tested with Microsoft Edge 25.10586.36.0).  It is also not supported in IE if the opener is in a different security zone.

In some browsers, a rel="noopener" attribute on the originating anchor tag will prevent the window.opener reference from being set.